# Ag-Grid Pie chart options values need to display with comma separated in graph

Tags: ag-grid, angular-chart

As I have tried the Ag-Grid pie chart to display some values in Graph but here I am not able to add comma-separated values. When I try to add values like 20,000 it's not accepting this format, so I have tried with string with parseInt('20,000') but values show in 20.0. Please check the below screenshot

[Example Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZePI.png)

Here I am expecting that values having comma separated or percentage means it needs to show the same format in the graph also